# Hide "Close Window" option from taskbar

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to make a window that has an icon on the taskbar, but does not have the option to be closed from there.  I could simply intercept WM_CLOSE, but then a non-functional option still remains on the window's taskbar menu.  There are other questions on stackoverflow pertaining to that method, but none that describe how to hide the option itself.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Taskbar button uses the same menu that is assigned to the window itself.  There is no way to differentiate whether the menu is being invoked by clicking on the Taskbar versus clicking on the window (or even if it is being invoked by mouse or keyboard, for that matter).  If you disable the "Close" item, the user would not be able to close the window at all.  So just don't do it.

Comment: Is there a way to hide anything closing the window altogether?  CS_NOCLOSE doesn't seem to do anything to the taskbar (my window is a WS_POPUP so it doesn't have a close option on the window anyway).

Comment: Use `GetSystemMenu()` to get the window's menu and then use `DeleteMenu()` to remove the "Close" item from it.